# Why isn't my a:hover:nth-child code working?

Tags: css, hover, css-selectors

This simple code is not working:

HTML:

```
<div id="topnav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="a.html">Aaaaaaa</a></li>
        <li><a href="b.html">Bbbbbbbb</a></li>
        <li><a href="c.html">Ccccccccc</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#topnav li a:hover:first-child{
    color:#ff0000;
    }

#topnav li a:nth-child(2):hover{
    color:#FF7700;
}

#topnav li a:nth-child(3):hover{
    color:#FFFF00;
}
```

Each link should have a different hover color. All of them show up as red. Why?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jeZHD/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because there is only one `<a>` per parent element. That means, every `<a>` is the first child of its parent `<li>`.

Try it on `<li>` instead.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jeZHD/2/

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
#topnav li:nth-child(1) a:hover { color:#ff0000; }
#topnav li:nth-child(2) a:hover { color:#FF7700; }
#topnav li:nth-child(3) a:hover { color:#FFFF00; }
```

Answer (score 0):

After wasting so much time on this, I just realized that the nth-child should be on the `li`'s, not the `a`'s. Like so:

```
#topnav li:first-child a:hover{
    color:#ff0000;
    }

#topnav li:nth-child(2) a:hover{
    color:#FF7700;
    }

    #topnav li:nth-child(3) a:hover{
    color:#FFFF00;
    }
```